# Memory not released in Azure DataBricks

Tags: azure, pyspark, memory-leaks, databricks, azure-databricks

In Azure DataBricks (12.2 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12) I am running the following code in the Notebook on compute Standard_DS5_v2:

```
df_spark = spark.sql(my_qyery_to_delta_table)
df_pandas = df_spark.toPandas()
df_spark.unpersist()

import gc
del df_pandas
del df_spark
gc.collect()
```

Data fetching takes a few minutes to execute (it is significant amount of data containing e.g. large nested jsons in columns). However I observe that the memory is not released after this process (screen). How to fix this and what is the origin of this?

[image]

[EDIT] Also approach with using df.unpersist() does not help. Moreover neither "del df" nor "df = None" before gc.collect() change anything in Memory level visible in Ganglia cluster's panel.

Answer (score 1):

- The issue you are experiencing is because that the `toPandas()` method returns a Pandas DataFrame, which is stored in memory on the driver
  node.

When you delete the df variable and run `gc.collect()`, you are only releasing the memory used by the Pandas DataFrame, but not the memory used by the Spark DataFrame that was created earlier.

To release the memory used by the Spark DataFrame, you can call the `unpersist()` method on the DataFrame after you are done using it.
I have created  an example:

```
delta_df = spark.read.format("delta").load(delta_table_path)
df_pandas = delta_df.toPandas()
df_filtered.unpersist()
gc.collect()
print(df_pandas.head())
```

**Result:**

```
The count of filtered rows is: 500
    id      name
0  751  Name_751
1  752  Name_752
2  753  Name_753
3  754  Name_754
4  755  Name_755
```

By calling `df_filtered.unpersist()`, I am releasing the memory used by the Spark DataFrame.
This method should help you reduce the memory usage on the driver node and prevent out-of-memory errors.

In the above code Converting Spark DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame
Using the Unpersist or droping the Spark DataFrame.
This step is important to release Spark-side resources
You can use either `df_filtered.unpersist()` or `df_filtered = None`
Then explicitly calling garbage collection and then you can continue working with `df_pandas` as needed

Comment: Thanks for reply! Unfortunately with your suggestion I observe same behavior :/

Comment: you can try running VACUUM command  on the Delta table.
spark.sql(f"VACUUM delta.`{your_delta_table_path}`")

Comment: Hello @DileeprajnarayanThumula isn't unpersist used only to remove df from cache?